# How to come over this issue: Select on views created based on some other views is slow

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I want to create a view in MySQL. As you may already know, MySQL does not support sub-queries. So I had to create a view for each sub-query I am using in my main view.

I have created my view. But I noticed that `SELECT` on this view is pretty much slow and this is because it is created over some other views. (Normal views are fast, but this one is not)

I wonder whether there is a solution for this problem?
Is there any technique which can be applied to make it faster?
Is there any other way, not to make views instead of sub-queries?

Comment: Can you share your query? If might be possible to create a view without using sub-queries

Comment: If that had been possible, I would have tried it. I am looking for a general solution for this problem. Changing queries, tables, models are my temporary solution. (In fact that's what I had to do in the end)

Comment: This is limitation of MySQL and the only work around is to create a view using other views or changing the queries, tables etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your queries with sub-queries. Most of them can be refactored, just use JOIN clauses instead of sub-queries.

About the views in MySQL, they may be slow, here it is an article about performance - [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/).